# Excel VBA Runtime Error 1004 while looping through sheets and extracting data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing an excel VBA script to loop through a set of 4 sheets, find a string at the top of a column of data, loop through all the data in that column and print the header and data in a summary tab.

I'm new to VBA and even after extensive research can't figure out why I'm getting Runtime error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error."

Here is the VBA code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim HeaderList(1 To 4) As String, sheet As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer, Summary As Worksheet

  'Define headers to look for
   HeaderList(1) = "Bananas"
   HeaderList(2) = "Puppies"
   HeaderList(3) = "Tigers"

    'Loop through each sheet looking for the right header
    For Each sheet In Workbooks("Tab Extraction Test.xlsm").Worksheets
        i = i + 1
        'Debug.Print i
        'Debug.Print HeaderList(i)
        Set h = Cells.Find(What:=HeaderList(i))

        With Worksheets("Summary")
            Worksheets("Summary").Cells(1, i).Value = h
        End With

        Col = h.Column
        Debug.Print Col
        Row = h.Row
        Debug.Print Row
        j = Row

        'Until an empty cell in encountered copy the value to a summary tab
        Do While IsEmpty(Cells(Col, j)) = False
            j = j + 1
            V = Range(Col, j).Value
            Debug.Print V
            Workbooks("Tab Extraction Test.xlsm").Worksheets("Summary").Cells(j, i).Value = V

        Loop

    Next sheet

End Sub
```

The error occurs at

```
Worksheets("Summary").Cells(1, i).Value = h
```

From other posts I thought this might be because I was trying to add something to a different cell than the one that was active in the current loop so I added a With statement but to no avail.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You probably need to check that that value is found, i.e. h is not nothing. Also you don't specify a sheet when you set h so it will be the active sheet by default.

Comment: what is the value oh `h` ? you need to handle the scenario that `Set h = Cells.Find(What:=HeaderList(i))` fails. Use `If not h Is Nothing Then` before the line you encountered your error

Comment: @SJR Well I think I want it to be the active sheet since the point of the loop is to go from sheet to sheet. Is there another way to do what I want?

Comment: @Shai The value of h is the result of the .Find search which is a string. Adding an if statement as a checker is definitely good practice but I don't think its causing my current error. I'd prefer to solve the 1004 and then make the code prettier and account for more possible cases

Comment: @Krossfire9 looping through sheets doesn't mean necessarily Activating them. Also, use a different name than `sheet` like `ws`. And the first line inside the loop just add `With ws` and nest anything underneath with `.` to qualify the object with this sheet.

Comment: My guess is that you need `Set h = sheet.Cells.Find(What:=HeaderList(i))` because the active sheet doesn't change in your code. Step through your code to check h is found.

Comment: @Shai if I use a 'with ws' for everything on the current sheet of the loop, do I have to have a 'with Summary' in the middle to copy the values to that page? Is it usual practice to nest with statements like that?

Comment: @SJR I added the "sheet." to the code and still got the error. Is there anything else I would have to change?

Comment: Find has many parameters and you may need to specify at least some of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments above, try the code below.

**Note**: I think your `Cells(Row, Col)` is mixed-up, I haven't modified it yet in my answer below. I think `Cells(Col, j)` should be `Cells(j, Col)` , no ?

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim HeaderList(1 To 4) As String, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, Summary As Worksheet
    Dim h As Range, Col As Long

    'Define headers to look for
    HeaderList(1) = "Bananas"
    HeaderList(2) = "Puppies"
    HeaderList(3) = "Tigers"

    ' set the "Summary" tab worksheet
    Set Summary = Workbooks("Tab Extraction Test.xlsm").Worksheets("Summary")

    'Loop through each sheet looking for the right header
    For Each ws In Workbooks("Tab Extraction Test.xlsm").Worksheets
        With ws
            i = i + 1
            Set h = .Cells.Find(What:=HeaderList(i))

            If Not h Is Nothing Then ' successful find
                Summary.Cells(1, i).Value = h.Value

                j = h.Row
                'Until an empty cell in encountered copy the value to "Summary" tab
                ' Do While Not IsEmpty(.Cells(h.Column, j))
                Do While Not IsEmpty(.Cells(j, h.Column)) ' <-- should be
                    j = j + 1
                    Summary.Cells(j, i).Value = .Cells(j, h.Column).Value
                Loop
                Set h = Nothing ' reset range object
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! The code executed without error but didn't find the dummy data I entered into the excel file. I'll have to do some debugging to find out why. Thanks for helping to solve the runtime error 1004!

Comment: And yes. It should be `Cells(j, Col)` Unfortunately, that didn't help find my results though. Back to debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim HeaderList As Variant, ws As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer, Summary As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, colNum As Long
    HeaderList = Array("Bananas", "Puppies", "Tigers", "Lions")

    For Each ws In Workbooks("Tab Extraction Test.xlsm").Worksheets
        lastCol = ws.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
        For k = 1 To lastCol
            For i = 0 To 3
                Set h = ws.Range(Chr(k + 64) & "1").Find(What:=HeaderList(i))
                If Not h Is Nothing Then
                    lastRow = ws.Range(Chr(h.Column + 64) & "65536").End(xlUp).Row
                    colNum = colNum + 1
'                   The below line of code adds a header to summary page (row 1) showing which workbook and sheet the data came from
'                   If you want to use it then make sure you change the end of the follpowing line of code from "1" to "2"
'                   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(Chr(colNum + 64) & "1").Value = Left(ws.Parent.Name, Len(ws.Parent.Name) - 5) & ", " & ws.Name
                    ws.Range(Chr(h.Column + 64) & "1:" & Chr(h.Column + 64) & lastRow).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(Chr(colNum + 64) & "1")
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        Next k
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to remove blank sheets. Say you have 2k sheets because you combined a bunch of txt files into one workbook. But they're all in one column. So you loop through to do a text2columns. It does some of them but not all of them. It stops to give you run-time error 1004. Try removing blank sheets before looping through to do text2columns or something else.

Sub RemoveBlankSheets_ActiveWorkbook()
'PURPOSE: Delete any blanks sheets in the active workbook
'SOURCE: [www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault](http://www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault)

```
Dim sht As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sht.Cells) = 0 And _
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count > 1 Then sht.Delete
Next sht

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```